# How can I insert css in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my script

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function pic1()
        {
            document.getElementById("img").src = "../images/images/1.png";
        }
        function pic2()
        {
            document.getElementById("img").src = "../images/images/2.png";
        }
</script>
```

This is my html

```
<span class="background" style="width: 950px; height: 642px; top: 0px; left: 0px">
</span>
<span class="car">
<img src = "../images/images/1.png" id = "img" /> 
</span>
<span class="car2">
<img src = "../images/thumbs/3.png"<input type="button" value="show"onclick="pic2()" />
</span>
```

And I want to add css for each element as "Images" to be showed in one position and thumb in other. It should to be something like this. Car or pic2() should to be in middle of page and car-colour in bottom side of page.

```
        .car
        {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin:0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 638px; 
            height: 274px; 
            top: 200px; 
            left: 150px;
        }
        .car-colour
        {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin:0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 70px; 
            height: 70px; 
            top: 500px; 
            left: 80px;
        }
```

SOLVED

```
        .car
        {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin:0;
            padding: 0;
        }

<span class="car" style="width: 638px; height: 274px; top: 200px; left: 150px;">
<img src = "../images/images/1.png" id = "img" />
</span>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add additional classes to the elements?

Comment: Done sorry for question I should to put the css inside <span class="" style="">

Comment: You can also have it in a separate css file and add a link to the file in your html like <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet " href="your css file path">

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate css file is better.

Style.css :

```
.car
{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
{

#img
{
    width: 638px;
    height: 274px; 
    top: 200px; 
    left: 150px;
{
```

Page.html :

```
<head>
...
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet " href="style.css">
...
</head>
<body>
...
<span class="car">
<img src = "../images/images/1.png" id = "img" />
</span>
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Span is inline element of block level element, and image has its owne width and height so boarder height 
could not apply to over image.

Try with the below url:[Sample URL][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/sathyanaga/4x4jvr00/
```